# Preguntar antes de recargar/cambiar pagina

Tags: javascript

Me refiero a confirmar si esta seguro de salir de la pagina actual

tengo un formulario, y quiero preguntar si el formulario tiene algun campo llenado si esta seguro de recargar/salirse la pagina

actualmente estoy usando

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return "You have some unsaved changes";
};
```

pero eso funciona aunque no tengo ningun campo llenado

Comment: te refieres a validaciones?, quieres hacer como una pregunta con modal, si es así, te recomiendo usar `sweet alert` para ventanas de preguta.En cuanto a validar formularios te recomiendo usar la propiedad html5 `onsubmit=" nombrefuncionJavascrpit()"` en la etiqueta de apertura de form.

Comment: me refiero a confirmar si esta seguro de salir de la pagina actual

Comment: entonces puedes usar el sweet alert, para peguntar si quieres salir, te dejo un ejemplo como respuesta

Comment: Abajo te deje una repuesta, ponlo en pantalla completa para que lo veas.

Answer (score 2):

Te faltará comprobar, antes de mostrar el mensaje, si ha habido o no cambio en el formulario. Los controles del formulario tienen una propiedad (que depende del tipo de control) en la que se guarda el valor inicial que tenían al generar la página.

En base a eso puedes hacer una función genérica:

```
function formIsDirty(form) {
for (var i = 0; i &lt; form.elements.length; i++) {
var element = form.elements[i];
var type = element.type;
if (type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") {
  if (element.checked != element.defaultChecked) {
    return true;
  }
}
else if (type == "hidden" || type == "password" ||
         type == "text" || type == "textarea") {
  if (element.value != element.defaultValue) {
    return true;
  }
}
else if (type == "select-one" || type == "select-multiple") {
  for (var j = 0; j &lt; element.options.length; j++) {
    if (element.options[j].selected !=
        element.options[j].defaultSelected) {
      return true;
    }
  }
}
}
 return false;
}
```

Y en el **beforeunload**:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
e = e || window.event;  
if (formIsDirty(document.forms["tu_formulario"])) {
// For IE and Firefox
if (e) {
  e.returnValue = "You have unsaved changes.";
}
// For Safari
return "You have unsaved changes.";
}
};
```

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo funcional porfavor

Answer (score 1):

Mira esto es un sweet alert como ejemplo para que lo puedas usar.

```js
$('button').click(function(){

  swal({
    title: "Aviso",
    text: "Esta seguro que desea salir?",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
    confirmButtonText: "Salir",
    cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
    closeOnConfirm: false,
    closeOnCancel: false
  },
  function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
      location.href ="http://www.pagina1.com";
    } else {
      swal("Cancelado", "Usted esta aqui", "error");
    }
  });

  });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<button>Irse</button>
```

algo asi se me ocurre, Pon en pantalla completa, para que veas como queda.Espero que te sirva. Saludos!